# Why changes are not saved in file in SVG-Edit?

Tags: javascript, svg

```
function FileLoad(file) {
    svgEditor.loadFromURL(file);
    var svg = document.getElementById("svgID");
    code continues....
}
```

I am trying to manipulate a svg after it gets load.

But the code is not further executed,neither it is shown in developer tool

I am using SVG-Edit toool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`svgEditor.loadFromURL()`](https://svg-edit.github.io/svgedit/releases/latest/docs/jsdoc/module-SVGEditor.html#.loadFromURL) returns a Promise. Loading, by its nature, is always an asynchronuous operation. You need to wait until it is done:

```
function FileLoad(file) {
    svgEditor.loadFromURL(file).then(function () {
        var svg = document.getElementById("svgID");
        // code continues....
    }, function (error) {
        // load error handling
    });
}
```

From the naming of your function it looks as if you use it for instantiating an object. However you use the `FileLoad` function, notice that the SVG content will not be available synchronuously, but only after the promise has resolved. In the case of calling it with `new`, a possible pattern could look like this (the `callback` function containing everything you do with the instantiated object):

```
function FileLoad(file, callback) {
    svgEditor.loadFromURL(file).then(function () {
         var svg = document.getElementById("svgID");
         code continues....
    }, function (error) {
        // load error handling
    }).then(callback.bind(this));
}

fileInstance = new FileLoad(url, callback);
```

**Edit:** The function changed its signature with version 4.0.0. For version 3.2.0 and older, you [need to pass](https://svg-edit.github.io/svgedit/releases/svg-edit-3.2.0/docs/jsdoc/module-SVGEditor.html#.loadFromURL) a callback function in a config object:

```
function FileLoad(file) {
    svgEditor.loadFromURL(file, {
        callback: function (success) {
            if (success) {
                 var svg = document.getElementById("svgID");
                 // code continues....
            } else {
                // load error handling
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It gives me the error :Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: Which line, exactly?

Comment: svgEditor.loadFromURL(file).then(function () {    :this line

Comment: isn't your svgEditor variable an instance of the SVGEditor class? Which version are you runing?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience and support..Its working now.I just got one thing I am storing a value in hiddenfield which i want to access in this function but it gives this error : Cannot read property 'value' of null

 var svg = document.getElementById("svgID");


var dbValue = document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>').value

Comment: Hi, For me "svgEditor" is null. Can any one tell me how to assign value for this.?